# Matlab: How to obtain magnitude and phase of a sinusoidal signal

Tags: matlab

Given two signals:

```
x1 = A1*exp(j*2*pi*f1*t + Phi1); 
x2 = A1*exp(j*2*pi*f1*t + Phi1) + A2*exp(j*2*pi*f2*t + Phi2);
```

Matlab should be able to calculate magnitude and phase:

```
abs(x1) = A1;
angle(x1) = Phi1;

abs(x2) = A1+A2;
angle(x2) = Phi1+Phi2;
```

Is this correct? I am really not sure about x2. 
Now, I am given a sinusoidal signal:

```
x3 = A3*cos(2*pi*f3*t + Phi3); 
x4 = A3*cos(2*pi*f3*t + Phi3) + A4*cos(2*pi*f4*t + Phi4);
```

What will abs() / angle() of these signals yield?

The complex envelope of x2 is given by:

```
A1*exp(j*2*pi*(f1-f2)/2 t + Phi1) + A2*exp(j*2*pi*(f2-f1)/2 t + Phi2)
```

assuming a carrier frequency that is between f1 and f2.
The amplitude and also the phase of the complex envelope should be somewhat equivalent to the original signal. Now I wonder, is it?

Comment: The cosine is not a linear function. Therefore, the magnitude of the sum of cosines will not be the sum of the magnitude of cosines. Nor will be the phase. Phase doesn't make much sense actually, since your frequencies are different (note that the angle of xi changes with time!). The problem you are trying to solve is called harmonic retrieval (estimate A_i, f_i and Phi_i from a sampled sum of harmonics). You can solve it via Fourier analysis (DFT) or high-resolution algorithms such as MUSIC or ESPRIT. Have a look at those. Anyways, it is not as simple as taking angle(x), believe me.

Comment: thx, Florian! Can I ask you this as well: You say phase doesn't make sense with different frequencies. But can you tell me the phase of x2, assuming that f1 = -f2 ? Is it just Phi1 + Phi2 ?

Comment: No, what makes you think that? Phases only add when you multiply signals, not when you add them.

Comment: you're right, I don't know. I have added an extra line to my question. That is the problem, that I have. Maybe you can help? I'm kind of lost.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. So far you asked whether magnitude/phase of x2 is the sum of magnitude/phase of its components. The answer is clearly no. Now you added "the amplitude and also the phase of the complex envelope should be somewhat equivalent to the original signal" and again, the answer is no, e.g., the amplitude of x2 is modulated in time. In case you are trying to find A1, A2, Phi1, Phi2 from x2 please see my first reply. In case not, please specify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I know A1, A2, Phi1 and Phi2. But I consider the complex envelope and then change A1,A2,Phi1 and Phi2 of the complex envelope. Then I transform the complex envelope back to bandpass signal. I thought, since it is the complex envelope, this should be somewhat similar to changing A1,A2,Phi1,Phi2 from the bandpass signal. I know it won't be exactly the same, since I am missing out on the carrier frequency. But I thought at least it would be close. .. maybe I am not describing the problem very good.

Comment: Yes, maybe... at least I still have no clue what you are doing. What means "change A1, A2, Phi1, Phi2 of the complex envelope"? How do you do the bandpass <-> lowpass transform? Actually, I get more and more the feeling this is not at all a Matlab question, but maybe a math.stackexchange one. I'd recommend you opening a question there and explaining with formulas exactly every step you make and what you are trying to achieve. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I am still not sure what exactly you need, but perhaps this identity might me helpful:

```
cos(a) = [exp(j*a) + exp(-j*a) ] / 2
```

If you need to estimate (some of) the parameters A, f, Phi, take a look at the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT). This page for example has the math of [least squares sinusoidal parameter estimation](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Least_Squares_Sinusoidal_Parameter.html).

Comment: Thx Giorgos! I have edited my question tho, I think it wasn't clear.

Comment: I updated my answer! Your x2 example is wrong, by the way :-)

Comment: Also, angle(x1) = (2*pi * f * t + Phi1) modulo 2*pi, not Phi1

Comment: ok, right. One last thing: abs() and angle() give the magnitude and phase of a complex number, right? And x2 will give a complex number. So at least with x2 I can apply these functions?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can.